# Error: jpeg-turbo: undefined method `on_intel' for

Tags: homebrew

when I using this command to install graphviz, shows error like this:

```
➜  interview-question git:(master) brew install graphviz
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Error: jpeg-turbo: undefined method `on_intel' for #<Class:0x000000014591bec8>
```

why did this happen? what should I do to avoid this problem? this is the brew doctor output:

```
➜  interview-question git:(master) brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Suspicious https://github.com/Homebrew/brew git origin remote found.
The current git origin is:
  https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/brew.git

With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't update properly.
You can solve this by setting the origin remote:
  git -C "/opt/homebrew" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-config

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/ansidecl.h
  /usr/local/include/bfd.h
  /usr/local/include/bfd_stdint.h
  /usr/local/include/bfdlink.h
  /usr/local/include/ctf-api.h
  /usr/local/include/ctf.h
  /usr/local/include/diagnostics.h
  /usr/local/include/dis-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/plugin-api.h
  /usr/local/include/symcat.h

Warning: Unbrewed '.la' files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected '.la' files:
  /usr/local/lib/libbfd.la
  /usr/local/lib/libctf-nobfd.la
  /usr/local/lib/libctf.la
  /usr/local/lib/libopcodes.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libbfd.a
  /usr/local/lib/libctf-nobfd.a
  /usr/local/lib/libctf.a
  /usr/local/lib/libopcodes.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  qt@5
  openjdk
  python@3.10
  jpeg-turbo

Warning: Some installed formulae are not readable:
  qt@5: undefined method `on_arm' for #<Resource::PatchResource:0x0000000124189af0>

  openjdk: undefined method `on_arm' for #<Resource:0x000000010410d768>

  snappy: undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass

  cocoapods: undefined method `on_arm' for #<Class:0x00000001031e1910>

  jpeg-turbo: undefined method `on_intel' for #<Class:0x00000001049fac90>
```

Comment: Hi! Does the `brew doctor` diagnosis ask for any relevant fixes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try to update macOS (**Apple icon** > **System Preferences** > **Software Update** > **Update**)

Comment: The output of `brew doctor` is already in the question, there is no reference to CLT in there.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but it‘s still unclear how an OS update will solve any of the problems listed in the question.